# Firebase does not throw onChildRemove

Tags: android, sqlite, listener, firebase

I am creating an Android app using firebase as backend. Now I am facing a problem with deleted nodes. How can I get informed, if a node is deleted after being completely logged out and offline?

The problem consists of three steps:

1. I close the app completely

   - event listeners become unregistered
   - logged out from firebase
2. Someone deletes one or more shared nodes from firebase

   - deletion is visible in firebase forge
3. open the app (connect and initialize event listeners in background)

   - log in to firebase with account
   - register event listener to firebase ref

Now firebase pushes new nodes via the onChildAdded method, but does not call onChildRemoved for the deleted nodes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just compare the onChildAdded to what you've stored locally, or discard what you've stored locally and use the new added events?

Comment: I have implemented your approach and it works fine. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?